# AspNet WebApi core JWT token not Authenticating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am building an api and I cannot get Authorization to work.

I have removed the Authorize attribute and verified the endpoint works.

My ConfigureServices Method

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options =>
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("default");
            Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SomeContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;

            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Roles.Manager, policy=> policy.RequireClaim(Roles.Manager));
            options.AddPolicy(Roles.Admin, policy=> policy.RequireClaim(Roles.Admin));
        });


        // add other services here
  }

My Configure method:


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });


    }
```

and my token:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Login(User user)
    {
        var identityUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.Username);
        var canSignIn = await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(identityUser);

        if (!canSignIn) return Unauthorized();

        var signResult = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(identityUser, user.Password, false);
        if (!signResult.Succeeded) return Unauthorized();

        var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(identityUser);
        var claims = (await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(identityUser)).ToList();

        claims.AddRange(userRoles.Select(x=> new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, x)));

        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConstantsToAddToSecrets.Seceret));
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken
        (
        ConstantsToAddToSecrets.Issuer,
        ConstantsToAddToSecrets.Audience,
        claims,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        signingCredentials
        );

       

        return Ok(
            new {access_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtToken)}
            );
    }
```

and finally my basic controller:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/test")]
public class TestController:Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "IWorked";
    }
}
```

Now on to my question, when I send the bearer token in the Headers of postman which looks something like `bearer my-token-here` what checks the bearer token, and why would I get a 404 not found when I add the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller?

**Update**
I have changed the following code:(and went from getting a 404 to now a 401)

```
        services.AddAuthorization( options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy =
                new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

            // options.AddPolicy(Roles.Manager, policy=> policy.RequireClaim(Roles.Manager));
            // options.AddPolicy(Roles.Admin, policy=> policy.RequireClaim(Roles.Admin));
            //
            // options.InvokeHandlersAfterFailure = true;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication("")
            .AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
            {
                configureOptions.Audience = ConstantsToAddToSecrets.Audience;
               
                configureOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
                configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    AudienceValidator = null,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateActor = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateTokenReplay = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with this issue, I found the resolution [Here On YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWkPdurauaA).

He has it on his blog [Here](https://dotnetcorecentral.com/blog/authentication-handler-in-asp-net-core/)

The end result was:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.ConstantsToAddToSecrets.Seceret));
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

And when creating a token to use the `tokenHandler`

public async Task AuthenticateAsync(LoginModel loginModel)
{
var signedInUser = await SigninAsync(loginModel);
if (signedInUser == null) return null;

```
        var claims = (await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(signedInUser)).ToList();
        var userRoles = await GetRolesAsync(signedInUser);

        claims.AddRange(userRoles);

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.ConstantsToAddToSecrets.Seceret));
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims.ToArray()), 
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                securityKey, 
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature
                ),
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IT seems you haven't added any JWT processing middleware to the authorisation flow. This works for me, using Azure AD:

```
            var azureAd = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy =
                    new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(x =>
                {
                    x.Audience = azureAd.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
                    x.Authority = $"{azureAd.GetValue<string>("Instance")}/{azureAd.GetValue<string>("TenantId")}/v2.0";
                    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    x.SaveToken = true;
                    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        AudienceValidator = null,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateActor = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateTokenReplay = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true
                    };
                });
```

Comment: I think this is getting me closer, however, I have gone from getting a 404 to now a 401. I will update the above. I am not using azure. I am logging with the database users.